# camera tagged as keyboard by udev why? See syslog output below

Tags: udev

erik@X18:~$ cat Insp-camera-connect
THE CAMERA is connected to USB-port.

```
erik@X18:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:0177 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0-CRW
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b725 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Glide
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
**Bus 003 Device 017: ID 093a:2620 Pixart Imaging, Inc.            <------ This is the camera**
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Syslog output

```
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287932.805345] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287932.933407] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.191218] usb 3-1: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 1 endpoint 0x6 has invalid wMaxPacketSize 0
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.191222] usb 3-1: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 2 endpoint 0x6 has invalid wMaxPacketSize 0
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.191223] usb 3-1: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 3 endpoint 0x6 has invalid wMaxPacketSize 0
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.191224] usb 3-1: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 4 endpoint 0x6 has invalid wMaxPacketSize 0
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.191225] usb 3-1: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 5 endpoint 0x6 has invalid wMaxPacketSize 0
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.191226] usb 3-1: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 6 endpoint 0x6 has invalid wMaxPacketSize 0
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.191227] usb 3-1: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 7 endpoint 0x6 has invalid wMaxPacketSize 0
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.191228] usb 3-1: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 8 endpoint 0x6 has invalid wMaxPacketSize 0
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.191230] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2620, bcdDevice= 1.00
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.191232] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.193461] gspca_main: gspca_pac7302-2.14.0 probing 093a:2620
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 kernel: [1287933.193673] input: gspca_pac7302 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/input/input29
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 17: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 17 was not an MTP device
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 systemd-udevd[243424]: 3-1:1.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cameractrls_cameractrls /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 systemd-udevd[243424]: 3-1:1.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cameractrls_cameractrlsgtk /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 systemd-udevd[243423]: 3-1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cameractrls_cameractrls /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 systemd-udevd[243423]: 3-1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cameractrls_cameractrlsgtk /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device gspca_pac7302 (/dev/input/event14)
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (**) gspca_pac7302: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'gspca_pac7302'
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event14 13:78 fd 66 paused 0
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (**) gspca_pac7302: always reports core events
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event14"
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 systemd-udevd[243422]: 3-1:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cameractrls_cameractrls /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 systemd-udevd[243422]: 3-1:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cameractrls_cameractrlsgtk /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 17: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 17 was not an MTP device
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 systemd-udevd[243422]: 3-1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cameractrls_cameractrls /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1 189:272' failed with exit code 1.
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 systemd-udevd[243422]: 3-1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cameractrls_cameractrlsgtk /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1 189:272' failed with exit code 1.
***Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (II) event14 - gspca_pac7302: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard***
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (II) event14 - gspca_pac7302: device is a keyboard
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (II) event14 - gspca_pac7302: device removed
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/input/input29/event14"
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "gspca_pac7302" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "se,gr"
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (**) Option "xkb_variant" ",nodeadkeys"
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp_led:scroll"
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (II) event14 - gspca_pac7302: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2477]: (II) event14 - gspca_pac7302: device is a keyboard
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 rtkit-daemon[1587]: Supervising 10 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 rtkit-daemon[1587]: Successfully made thread 243464 of process 2337 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 rtkit-daemon[1587]: Supervising 11 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 gnome-shell[2682]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 gnome-shell[2682]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 gnome-shell[2682]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 gnome-shell[2682]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 gnome-shell[2682]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 gnome-shell[2682]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 gnome-shell[2682]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 gnome-shell[2682]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Aug  9 10:08:15 X18 gnome-shell[2682]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
erik@X18:~$
```